# Decomposition of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]
Gilbert strang says in his book

> Suppose $T$ is projection onto the line $L$ at angle $\theta$. To represent $T$ by a matrix, we do need a basis. Figure $5.5$ offers two choices, the standard basis $v_{1}=(1,0), v_{2}=(0,1)$ and a basis $V_{1}, V_{2}$ chosen especially for $T$.
> We express $V_{1}$ as a combination $v_{1} \cos \theta + v_{2} \sin \theta$ and Similarly $V_{2}$ is $-v_{1} \sin \theta+v_{2} \cos \theta$.

I'm not able to see how
$V_{1}= v_{1} \cos \theta + v_{2} \sin \theta$  $V_{2}=-v_{1} \sin \theta+v_{2} \cos \theta$.

Comment: It cannot be done because $||v_{1} \cos \theta + v_{2} \sin \theta||_2 = 1$ while $||V_1||_2 = \sqrt 2$. Similarly for the other vector.
The author forgot to normalize $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Comment: @peter a g, thank you for your reply. I understand the projection, my question is about the final two equations. How did the author decompse V into v.

Comment: @Kashmiri The decomposition the author suggests is not possible. And my argument here is that the length of the given decompositions is equal to $1$ while the lenghts of the supposed resulting vectors $V_1, V_2$ is equal to $\sqrt 2$.

So, you will never find such a decomposition as indicated.

Comment: @trancelocation, even if the normalisation is done, I can't see how the last two equations were written. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @peter a g, yes.

Comment: @peter a g,  V have length sqrt 2. The figure shows that but that's not my question it is about writing V as a sum of v

Comment: @Kashmiri Haven't I answered your question in my "If I am understanding your question:..." comment?

Comment: @peter could you please explain why cos with v1  & sin with v2 ?

Comment: @Kashmiri : The counterclockwise rotation of a vector by an angle $\theta$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$. That's where this composition comes into play from.

Comment: @Kashmiri I recommend that you play around with these rotations in geogebra or so to get a feeling how this works.

Comment: Thank you. The text says the $\theta=135$ deg but if I'm correct you suggest that the theta here is -45? That is a clockwise rotation?

Comment: @trancelocation, thank you. Your comment cleared up the doubt. Thank you

Comment: As you can see, I have deleted all of my now-cringe-inducing comments.... apologies once again! best wishes...

Comment: @Kashmiri Right. The given decomposition formulas belong to a counterclockwise rotation. The correct angle would be $\theta = 315°$. This indeed corresponds to a clockwise rotation of $\theta = 45°$ or "counterclockwise by $-45°$". :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the angle is $\theta=135°$ then $\cos\theta=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ and
$\sin\theta=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ too.
So the new (rotated from the canonical $v_1,v_2$ one) basis is
$$b_1=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(v_1+v_2),$$
$$b_2=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(v_1-v_2).$$
One can solve for $v_1,v_2$ to get
$$v_1=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(-b_1+b_2),$$
$$v_2=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(b_1+b_2).$$
then by subbing in $V_1=v_1+v_2$ and $V_2=v_1-v_2$ you will get
$$V_1=-\sqrt 2\ b_1,$$
$$V_2=\sqrt 2\ b_2.$$
Here, you have $V_1,V_2$ as linear combinations of that new basis.